# Dichotomizing Categorical Variables in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I very basically read a dataframe into Python then do some very basic data exploration:

```
data = pd.read_csv("S:/<File1.csv>"
data.dtypes
```

All of the columns are read in as object types except for the first and last columns. var1 - var7 are all categorical variables with many levels in the middle of the dataset:

```
categorical_features = ['var1','var2','var3',var4','var5','var6','var7'] 
for col in categorical_features: #for each categorical col
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(data[col], prefix=col) #one-hot-encoding
    data = pd.concat([data, dummies], axis=1) #append to data
    data.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True) #drop orig column
```

But I receive errors. I know the code works when my listing of categorical features are all int64, but I cannot do that as there are many characters in my seven variables.

Below is a listing of the error I receive:

```
  File "<ipython-input-20-388dc6340151>", line 2, in <module>
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(data[col], prefix=col) #one-hot-encoding
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  KeyError: 'var1'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing looks right.

The error you're receiving happens when the named column doesn't exist in the DataFrame, when running `df['var1'`]. It isn't related to the data type of the column.

Double check that the names of columns loaded from the CSV exactly match the ones in  `categorical_features`, and don't include leading or trailing spaces, or other slight differences.

The third line of the Traceback shows `__getitem__`, which is the private python function called when using square braces on an object. This runs before `get_dummies()` is called.

Comment: It was due to capitalization. Please clarify how the new dichotomized columns are numbered/ordered. For example, var1 has 63 different categories or levels and they correctly create 63 different columns. However, the new columns are in an interesting order: var1_1, var1_10, var1_11, var1_13 - it skipped the 12. Also, after it gets to var1_99 then it creates new columns such as var1_A0, var1_A4, var1_A5, and var1_B4. I cannot figure out the pattern - is there one?

Comment: That's probably worth starting a new question about.

It looks like it's doing string, or alphanumeric, ordering, instead of by number alone, and as for the letters, I don't know.